# popup opens on click anything to navbar

Tags: javascript, html

The Problem I'm facing is, whenever i want to click any item in navbar , the popup opens.  if that item has link "#" . 
and what i want is the popup should open only onclick "Login/Signup" item.
here is the llink of actual codepen version you can check it here: [click here or go to https://codepen.io/codyhouse/pen/pIrbg](https://codepen.io/codyhouse/pen/pIrbg)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $form_modal = $('.cd-user-modal'),
        $form_login = $form_modal.find('#cd-login'),
        $form_signup = $form_modal.find('#cd-signup'),
        $form_forgot_password = $form_modal.find('#cd-reset-password'),
        $form_modal_tab = $('.cd-switcher'),
        $tab_login = $form_modal_tab.children('li').eq(0).children('a'),
        $tab_signup = $form_modal_tab.children('li').eq(1).children('a'),
        $forgot_password_link = $form_login.find('.cd-form-bottom-message a'),
        $back_to_login_link = $form_forgot_password.find('.cd-form-bottom-message a'),
        $main_nav = $('.hmodal');

    //open modal
    $main_nav.on('click', function(event) {

        if ($(event.target).is($main_nav)) {
            // on mobile open the submenu
            $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');
        } else {
            // on mobile close submenu
            $main_nav.children('ul').removeClass('is-visible');
            //show modal layer
            $form_modal.addClass('is-visible');
            //show the selected form
            ($(event.target).is('.cd-signup')) ? signup_selected(): login_selected();
        }

    });

    //close modal
    $('.cd-user-modal').on('click', function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).is($form_modal) || $(event.target).is('.cd-close-form')) {
            $form_modal.removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    });
    //close modal when clicking the esc keyboard button
    $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which == '27') {
            $form_modal.removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    });

    //switch from a tab to another
    $form_modal_tab.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ($(event.target).is($tab_login)) ? login_selected(): signup_selected();
    });

    //hide or show password
    $('.hide-password').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            $password_field = $this.prev('input');

        ('password' == $password_field.attr('type')) ? $password_field.attr('type', 'text'): $password_field.attr('type', 'password');
        ('Hide' == $this.text()) ? $this.text('Show'): $this.text('Hide');
        //focus and move cursor to the end of input field
        $password_field.putCursorAtEnd();
    });

    //show forgot-password form 
    $forgot_password_link.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        forgot_password_selected();
    });

    //back to login from the forgot-password form
    $back_to_login_link.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        login_selected();
    });

    function login_selected() {
        $form_login.addClass('is-selected');
        $form_signup.removeClass('is-selected');
        $form_forgot_password.removeClass('is-selected');
        $tab_login.addClass('selected');
        $tab_signup.removeClass('selected');
    }

    function signup_selected() {
        $form_login.removeClass('is-selected');
        $form_signup.addClass('is-selected');
        $form_forgot_password.removeClass('is-selected');
        $tab_login.removeClass('selected');
        $tab_signup.addClass('selected');
    }

    function forgot_password_selected() {
        $form_login.removeClass('is-selected');
        $form_signup.removeClass('is-selected');
        $form_forgot_password.addClass('is-selected');
    }

    //REMOVE THIS - it's just to show error messages 
    $form_login.find('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $form_login.find('input[type="email"]').toggleClass('has-error').next('span').toggleClass('is-visible');
    });
    $form_signup.find('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $form_signup.find('input[type="email"]').toggleClass('has-error').next('span').toggleClass('is-visible');
    });


    //IE9 placeholder fallback
    if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
        $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.val('');
            }
        }).blur(function() {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
            }
        }).blur();
        $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
            $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
                var input = $(this);
                if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.val('');
                }
            })
        });
    }

});


jQuery.fn.putCursorAtEnd = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        // If this function exists...
        if (this.setSelectionRange) {
            // ... then use it (Doesn't work in IE)
            // Double the length because Opera is inconsistent about whether a carriage return is one character or two. Sigh.
            var len = $(this).val().length * 2;
            this.setSelectionRange(len, len);
        } else {
            // ... otherwise replace the contents with itself
            // (Doesn't work in Google Chrome)
            $(this).val($(this).val());
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
        <nav id="home" class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div>
                <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="logo" src="img/logo.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse hmodal">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding-right:15px;">
                        <li><button class="ui inverted compact small yellow button" style="margin-top:8px; ">Become a Partner</button></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Track</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tel:+917878000666" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Call +91 7878 000 666</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#notification"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a class="cd-signin" href="#Login">Login/Signup</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> Location</a>
  <div class="dialog" style="display:none">
  <div class="title">Add Event</div>
  <form action="#" method="post">
  
    <input type="submit" value="Ok"/>
  </form></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
            
        </nav>
```

Thanks in advance, i'm stuck here for two days. help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original script of open modal is opened by the `nav-menu`. you need to point the click event on those two buttons. Please try:

```
//open modal
    $(".cd-signin, .cd-signup").on('click', function(event){
      $main_nav.children('ul').removeClass('is-visible');
            $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');
      $form_modal.addClass('is-visible');   
      if($(this).hasClass("cd-signin"))
      {
          login_selected();
      }
      else
      {
         signup_selected();
      }

    });
```